# how to make SonarLint check for number of code line in java method

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

I am new to sonarLint I have tried it out and I am asking myself, if this tool can check the number of codeline of java method. It should print an error, if a method has more codeline than for example 80 lines. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule exists: https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#q=S138

It's not activated by default in SonarLint, though.

To use it, you need to bind SonarLint to a project in a SonarQube server which has that rule activated. You can also costumize the number of lines needed to trigger it.